# Tomcat 8 - Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

Just downloaded Apache Tomcat Windows Service Installer, installed it and tried to start it and got this error message.

`java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind`

I'm running a windows 7 64 bit box with Java 8 installed. I've also run netstat to check if the port is in use but it isn't.

Comment: Check this explanation: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/fixing-javanetbindexception-cannot-assign-requested-address-JVMbind.html

Comment: @J Smith - did you get this resolved?

Comment: ...No not yet - had a look at the link above, quite helpful says it's caused by `Typically, the port is in use, or the requested local address could not be assigned.` . Anyway, the port isn't in use and there should be no problem assigning the local address.

Comment: Ok got it working - in the hosts file `127.0.0.1` is mapped to `localhost` but you also need your internal IP to be mapped to `localhost` - i.e. 192.168.something.something

Comment: @J Smith - For whatever it's worth, I've *never* had to explicitly redefine my internal IP to "localhost" to get Tomcat working - *ever*.  Maybe something about Tomcat 8 and/or Java 8?  But  I'm glad you got it working - that's what counts.  Cool!

Comment: I completely agree - it's almost certainly an anomaly on my computer, but still a nice-to-know if other people encounter the same thing.